# Having docker compose issues

Tags: jhipster

Must admit I am not a docker guru, but despite begin logged into docker on the command line I am having issues:

```
AdminsMacBook-2:dockertest newadmin$ sudo docker-compose -f src/main/docker/app.yml up
Password:
WARNING: Found orphan containers (docker_dockertest-sonar_1) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the --remove-orphans flag to clean it up.
Pulling dockertest-app (dockertest:latest)...
ERROR: pull access denied for dockertest, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

here is the yaml file from the project:

```
AdminsMacBook-2:dockertest2 newadmin$ more src/main/docker/app.yml
version: '2'
services:
    dockertest2-app:
        image: dockertest2
        environment:
            - _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx512m -Xms256m
            - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod,swagger
            - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://dockertest2-mysql:3306/dockertest2?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
            - JHIPSTER_SLEEP=10 # gives time for the database to boot before the application
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
    dockertest2-mysql:
        extends:
            file: mysql.yml
            service: dockertest2-mysql
```

Here is the docker file:

```
AdminsMacBook-2:dockertest2 newadmin$ more src/main/docker/Dockerfile 
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

ENV SPRING_OUTPUT_ANSI_ENABLED=ALWAYS \
    JHIPSTER_SLEEP=0 \
    JAVA_OPTS=""

# Add a jhipster user to run our application so that it doesn't need to run as root
RUN adduser -D -s /bin/sh jhipster
WORKDIR /home/jhipster

ADD entrypoint.sh entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 755 entrypoint.sh && chown jhipster:jhipster entrypoint.sh
USER jhipster

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 8080

ADD *.war app.war
```

Comment: Please post your ```app.yml``` file and any related ```Dockerfile```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build the app's Docker image before you can start it.  `dockertest2` is not present in your local docker images.

> To create a Docker image of your application, and push it into your Docker registry:
>
> With Maven, type: `./mvnw package -Pprod verify jib:dockerBuild`
>
> With Gradle, type: `./gradlew -Pprod bootWar jibDockerBuild`
>
> This will package your application with the prod profile, and build a Docker image using Jib connecting to the local Docker daemon.

https://www.jhipster.tech/docker-compose/#3

Comment: for some reason when I tried that yesterday it didn't help, maybe proj was corrupt or something. Thanks